# package "state" vs "selection state"

Tags: package-management, dpkg, scripts, deb, installed-programs

All answers that I read, suggest listing/saving package *selection* states. i.e. `dpkg --get-selections`

But the *selection* state could be different from *actual*. So why use that?
Is it just because getting the actual package state is more involved?

For example getting "installed packages", has 2 possible solutions:

- get names of package whose **selection state** is **install** with
  `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`
- get names of packages whose **state** is **installed** with
  `dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep '^.i' | cut -d' ' -f3`

Unlike `dpkg --get-selections` `dpkg -l` is meant for viewing not processing. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --get-selections` only output the  package selection states not package states. Output of `dpkg -l`  contains the the package actual states however 
processing `dpkg -l` output is bit tough because of being more closer to the graphical approach.

So if you want to extract the package state , you can use `dpkg-query` tool.

It provide formatting option using `-f, --showformat=format`

From [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-query.1.html)

```
-f, --showformat=format
              This  option  is used to specify the format of the output --show
              will produce. The format is a string that  will  be  output  for
              each package listed.
```

So I have combined `${binary:Package}` field with `${Status}` to get the actual status of a package.

```
dpkg-query --show -f='${binary:Package} \t\t ${Status}\n'
```

For a more formatted output, you can use

```
dpkg-query --show -f='${binary:Package} ${Status}\n'  | awk '{ printf "%-60s %s\n", $1, $2" "$3" "$4}'
```

**Example**

*Using `dpkg -l`*

```
$dpkg -l vlc
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version              Architecture         Description
+++-==============================-====================-====================-=================================================================
hU  vlc                            2.2.0~pre2-4build1   amd64                multimedia player and streamer
```

*Using `dpkg-query --show`*

```
$ dpkg-query --show -f='${binary:Package} ${Status}\n' vlc  | awk '{ printf "%-60s %s\n", $1, $2" "$3" "$4}'
vlc                                                          hold ok unpacked
```

Comment: I was mainly interested in why people prefer the "selection state". But thanks.